# Ошибка запроса на сайт 'SSL [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'

Tags: python, ssl, requests

При запросе на на сайт через requests без указания параметра verify=False происходит ошибка SSL сертификата. Подскажите, что я возможно делаю не так, и каковы решения данной проблемы? Извиняюсь, если повторил какой-нибудь другой тред.

код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
 
cookies = {"sessionid": <session_ID>}
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"}
 
url = "https://harkiv-collegium.e-schools.info/teachers"
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
soup = BS(r.content, "html.parser")
soup = BS(r.content, "html.parser")
```

ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\bogda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='harkiv-collegium.e-schools.info', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /teachers (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: А в браузере Internet Explorer открывается?

Comment: Для верификации нужно указать путь к файлу сертификата или связке сертификатов. `verify='/path/to/certfile.cer'`

Comment: @NoSkill но ведь браузеры этого почему-то не требуют, значит должно работать без этого

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что браузеры этого не требуют? Удалите ваш сертификат с севера и зайдите на него по протоколу HTTP+SSL.

Comment: @NoSkill какой «наш сертификат»? У меня нет никакого сертификата, а сайт успешно открывается

Comment: Это потому, что браузер делает всю работу за вас. В програмировании вам нужно сделать всю работу самому.

Comment: @NoSkill почему тогда `requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')` работает и не требует никаких сертификатов?

Comment: Потому, что в этом случае verify=False. А автору явно нужно по другому.

Comment: @NoSkill почему тогда `requests.get('https://yandex.ru/', verify=True)` тоже работает и тоже не требует никаких сертификатов?

Comment: Потому, что по яндексу все находит... А по другому сайту - нет. Причин может быть тысячи! Может где-то что-то лежит просроченное.

Comment: @NoSkill значит нужно разобраться в причине, а не бездумно пихать verify)

Comment: В следующий раз когда столкнетесь - обязательно попробуйте разобраться.

Comment: @NoSkill зачем в следующий? Мы в этой базе знаний собрались именно для того чтобы разбираться и наполнять ресурс новыми знаниями, значит давайте разбираться сейчас, а не пихать verify на каждый чих)

Comment: Так разбирайтесь, кто вам запрещает? Я предложил свой вариант решения. Вы ищите другой.

Comment: @NoSkill он заведомо плохой, каждый раз заново скачивать сертификат при его обновлении — неудобно, а полностью отключать проверку — вообще опасно

Comment: @andreymal, звучит логично. Я слышал про это, но не понял как мне получить certfile.cer.

Comment: сертификат можете ПОПРОБОВАТЬ сохранить из браузера, например. А также весь его чейн - до корневого.

Comment: А вообще **истинная** причина проблемы в том, что сервер не присылает промежуточный сертификат (от Sectigo Limited) и в итоге requests не может составить цепочку доверия между сертификатом сайта и доверенным корневым сертификатом, зашитым в систему. И единственный **правильный** способ починки — связаться с администратором сайта и попросить его добавить недостающий промежуточный сертификат на веб-сервере. Полюбоваться на цепочку сертификатов можно [через SSLTest например](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=harkiv-collegium.e-schools.info&hideResults=on)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо!

Comment: @Jeimip ну и всё-таки — открывается ли сайт в Internet Explorer?

Comment: @andreymal нет(

Comment: @Jeimip в Windows отключены автоматические обновления? Если да, то очень-очень зря, потому что в обновлениях Windows есть этот самый недостающий промежуточный сертификат (что, впрочем, не отменяет того, что накосячил именно админ сайта)